# iOS Memory Heap keeps growing

Tags: ios, core-data, memory-management, heap-memory

I am hoping that this is just some simple thing that I just can't figure out.

I have a core data model with a class extension.

```
+(CDvitalsPO2Data *) newVitalDataInContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context {
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:po2EntityName inManagedObjectContext:context];
    CDvitalsPO2Data *newVitalsDataPoint = [[[CDvitalsPO2Data class] alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context];    
    return newVitalsDataPoint;
}
```

So this returns a new item in the context and of the po2 entity name. Great.

If I call this class extension from this code:

```
-(void) logPO2:(NSDictionary *)po2EntryDictionary forThisTime:(NSDate *)loggedTime inContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context {

if (context) {
        CDvitalsPO2Data *vitalsPO2Entry;
        vitalsPO2Entry  = [CDvitalsPO2Data newVitalDataInContext:context];
        vitalsPO2Entry.timeStamp  = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:[loggedTime timeIntervalSince1970]];

        vitalsPO2Entry.accelX = [po2EntryDictionary objectForKey:po2LogAccelX];
        vitalsPO2Entry.accelY = [po2EntryDictionary objectForKey:po2LogAccelY];
        vitalsPO2Entry.accelZ = [po2EntryDictionary objectForKey:po2LogAccelZ];
        vitalsPO2Entry.patchID = [po2EntryDictionary objectForKey:po2LogPatchID];
        vitalsPO2Entry.patchRSSI = [po2EntryDictionary objectForKey:po2LogPatchRSSI];
        vitalsPO2Entry.sequenceID = [po2EntryDictionary objectForKey:po2LogSequenceID];
        vitalsPO2Entry.sessionID = [po2EntryDictionary objectForKey:po2LogSessionID];
        vitalsPO2Entry.po2Value = [po2EntryDictionary objectForKey:po2LogValue];

        NSError *error;

        [[vitalsPO2Entry managedObjectContext] save:&error];
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"save error:%@",error);
        }
}
```

I get the object inserted into the context, it gets saved, but the heap just grows and grows. If this log runs once a second or once a minute, I just see the memory grow. I've put all kinds of weak pointers into the calls, tried setting things to nil, put an autorelease pool into places; nothing seems to slowdown, let alone stop the memory creep. I feel that there is just something fundamental that I'm missing. Shouldn't these objects get dumped once they goes out of scope after the context saves it? When I look in Instruments there seems to be a retain on the object, but it is at the system level, it is not from one of my routine calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the issues that I've seen are directly accountable to the Xcode Scheme.
Product->Scheme
Select Run-Options
UNCHECK -> Queue Debugging (enable backtrack recording)

Once this was done, all of the memory footprint growth immediately disappeared.